# How to keep the top lines of a file while scrolling down the page in vi editor

Tags: vi

I have a file opened with vim, how do I keep the top 10 header lines at the top all the time while I scroll down the page?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
esc : 10 sp
```

`ctrl-w` to switch between.

They are referred to as viewports in vi parlance.

Comment: [Wilshire](http://serverfault.com/users/84698/wilshire) wanted to add: "shift-ZZ to go back to normal viewing"

Comment: Note that the `split` comand (`sp` is short for `split`) is specific to `vim`.  These days it's a pretty safe bet that you if you're on a Linux system you *are* running `vim`, but it's worth noting that if you find yourself on a system with vanilla `vi` (FreeBSD, Solaris) that this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The keystrokes `ctrl-w s` will split the screen horizontally, and `ctrl-w ctrl-w` will switch your focus back and forth.  You can widen the current viewport with `ctrl-w +`, or make is smaller with (any guess?) `ctrl-w -`.

You can do vertical splits with `ctrl-w v`, and you can split a split to make fairly complex sets of viweports inside the vim screen.

Using `:q` will close your current viewport.